# Websockets ESP8266

Tags: websocket, at-command, esp8266

I'm trying to send data to a server with websocket in ESP8266, but the handshake don't work.

I'm sending the following sequence of AT commands:

```
AT+RST
AT+CWMODE=1
AT+CIPMODE=0
AT+CIPMUX=1
AT+CWJAP="ssid_my_network","password"
AT+CIPSTART=4,"TCP","ip_server",port
AT+CIPSEND=4,data_lenght
```

In this moment, i send the header:

```
GET ws:ip_server HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: ip_server\r\n
Upgrade: websocket\r\n
Connection: Upgrade\r\n
Sec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==\r\n
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n
```

But, i don't receive the response from server. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP headers must end with an empty line. You need to send another `\r\n`.

```
GET ws:ip_server HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: ip_server\r\n
Upgrade: websocket\r\n
Connection: Upgrade\r\n
Sec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==\r\n
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n
\r\n
```

Comment: Thank you! But I don't receive any response yet. I'll keep trying.

Comment: Are you sure that you are only terminating at commands with \r ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to use WiFiClient instead of WebSocket (like [this](http://shawnhymel.com/695/quick-tip-http-get-with-the-esp8266-thing/))

Some code from the above link to send a http GET request:

```
// Perform an HTTP GET request to a remote page
bool getPage() {

// Attempt to make a connection to the remote server
  if ( !client.connect(http_site, http_port) ) {
    return false;
  }

  // Make an HTTP GET request
  client.println("GET /index.html HTTP/1.1");
  client.print("Host: ");
  client.println(http_site);
  client.println("Connection: close");
  client.println();

  return true;
}
```

Comment: How this answer is related to websocket ?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing ws uri after handshaking GET request. If you have no path, make it "/" . Also if your websocket server is not serving from 80, you'd need to denote it in header after host attribute.

We might say a possible version mismatch had occured between peers, but no answer. So we have a tiny hidden problem like proxy etc.